# Additional non model database connections in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I need to connect to additional databases in Django. These databases do not have models and are not the core application database. I just need to execute SQL on an olap MySQL database. What is the best practice way to achieve this so that connection pooling occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/) topic in the django docs.

To [execute SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/) in the additional database use the following code:

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['my_additional_database'].cursor()
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM very_important_table");
```